# Finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are closed subsets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Consider a set $S$ containing finitely many elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, if $S=\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_N\}$, then $S=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^N \{x_i\}$, the union of the $N$ singletons. Since singletons are closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a finite union of closed sets is closed, $S$ must be closed.

Please let me know if this proof is OK.

Comment: Ok. It's fine. Good

Comment: Yep, nice job. Character minimum met.

Comment: Your prove is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a correct proof.

- I'm assuming you're perfectly happy to assume that singletons are closed. Prove it if you must.
- The main possible mistake is confusing finite union with infinite union. You did not make this mistake, so your proof is correct.
- You might think about the case of the empty set. Is the empty union of (zero) closed sets closed? You can treat it as a special case if you want to avoid this vacuous nonsense.